# Xamarin Android 6.0 Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError with View.SetText

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nosuchmethoderror

I have made a custom renderer for a Label that renders the HTML code as text.

When I try to set the formatted text this erro occurs:

**Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method "Landroid/text/Html;.fromHtml(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/text/Spanned;" occurred**

This is my piece of code:

```
Control.SetText(Html.FromHtml(View.Text.ToString(), FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
```

This happens only on Android 6.0, from 7.0 all works fine.

How can I solve this?

There is a workaround?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Jon Douglas i've solved in this way:

```
 if (global::Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= global::Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.N) {
   Control.SetText(Html.FromHtml(View.Text.ToString(), FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
 } else {
   // For API < 24 
   Control.SetText(Html.FromHtml(View.Text.ToString()), TextView.BufferType.Normal);
 }
```

For the "else" path, VisualStudio told me that are deprecated but it compiles anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an overloaded method that was introduced in API 24. Thus to properly support this, you will need a [runtime check](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#Runtime_Checks_for_Android_Versions) to check for `< API 24` values in which you will use a non-API 24 `Html.FromHtml` overload.

See the [Html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) class for overloads that you can appropriately use. For example:

1 Parameter Method for < API 24 -
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)

3 Parameter Method for < API 24 -
 [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String, android.text.Html.ImageGetter, android.text.Html.TagHandler)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler))

Comment: Thank you! This solve my problem. I have updated the main post with the solution.